# can you have more than 1 dictionary key that links to the same value

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I was wondering if its possible to have a dictionary in which there is 2 keys for the same item.
I don't know if I have explained that well but an example of what I mean is bellow

```
dictionary = {"key_1","key_2" : "value_1"}
```

This would have 2 keys but lead to the same value

Is there any way i can do this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Values can be equivalent but they won't be the same reference. ex: `{"key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_1" }`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, keys are the elements/items of the dictionary while values are the values paired with these keys, so yeah, you can have two keys whose values are equal but it would be like -

```
dictionary = {"key_1":"value_1", "key_2":"value_1"}
```

In case you are asking for a way to use two items together as a key then the answer is `tuples` -

```
dictionary = { ("key_1","key_2"): "value_1" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
dictionary = {"key_1": "value_1", "key_2" : "value_1"}
```